# Cast de object para um objeto criado em Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

### Problema

Boa tarde! é possível, em typescript, dar um cast de um `object` para uma classe que criei? Preciso justamente para validar se os campos existem ou não, e se estão preenchidos corretamente, então o risco de uma propriedade não existir não é um problema.

### Contexto

Estou fazendo uma API em typescript e me deparei com um problema: Um dos parâmetros que recebo é um objeto que pode variar de acordo com outros campos, e cada um dos objetos não tem nada a ver com o outro.

Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça (Queria validar tudo usando decorators, mas não consegui encontrar uma solução), acabei por deixar ele como um `object` mesmo

```js
config: object;
```

Beleza! Porém, pra validar, eu pensei em criar o objeto com o construtor (Ou então só ter um método de validação mesmo, no meu contexto não faz diferença). Comecei fazendo o seguinte:

```js
constructor(config: object)
{
    if(config.property !== undefined && config.property > 3)
            //ok
}
```

O que me retorna o erro `Property 'queryId' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)`. Entendo que o próprio typescript limita essas ações, mas realmente não sei prosseguir. Minha ideia foi dar um cast, essa é a aproximação correta? E, se sim, como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não costumo programar em TypeScript, mas uma das coisas que você pode fazer é checar se determinada propriedade existe dentro do objeto que está recebendo.

Por exemplo:

```js
constructor (config: object) 
{
    if ("id" in config) 
    {
        // Aqui é possível acessar a propriedade 'id'
        validar(config.id)
    }
    else if ("nome" in config) 
    {
        // Aqui é possível acessar a propriedade 'nome'
        validar(config.nome)
    }
}
```

Apesar de eu não ter tanta proficiência com TypeScript eu indicaria que você ainda usada interfaces bem definidas no construtor ao invés de `object`, porque isso com certeza vai facilitar muito para quem for consumir essa API uma vez que vai ter claramente o que pode ou não passar como parâmetro.

Se este construtor aceita tipos diferentes, o TypeScript tem uma funcionalidade chamada *Union Types* que pode ajudar.

Adaptando o exemplo acima para usar *Union Types*.

```js
constructor (config: ConfigA | ConfigB) 
{
    if ("id" in config) 
    {
        validar(config.id)
    }
    else if ("nome" in config) 
    {        
        validar(config.nome)
    }
}
```

Desta forma, que for usar este construtor sabe que ele aceita objetos que combinam com a interface `ConfigA` ou com a interface `ConfigB`.